# Indenting all lines in a theorem environment

Tags: theorems

I have made the following theorem environment

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheoremstyle{proposition}
{.5\baselineskip}
{.5\baselineskip}
{}                              % body
{}                              % indentation
{}{}
{.5em}                          % after head
{\thmnumber{(#2)}}              % head
\theoremstyle{proposition}
\newtheorem{prop}{}


\begin{document}

\begin{prop}
  Necessarily if there is life on the Evening Star then
there is life on the Evening Star.
\end{prop}

\end{document}
```

[image]

But now the second line is aligned with the ''head'' rather than the
beginning of the text.  Can that be changed?

Also, is it possible to make the indentation fixed relative to the left
margin rather than the end of the head (which may vary in width)?

I'd like something similar to the following

[image: quine]

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/230559/134144 might be interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems quite like the original:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[textwidth=275pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{thminner}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[thminner]{
  label=(\arabic*),
  ref=\arabic*,
  leftmargin=3em,
  labelwidth=*,
  topsep=\smallskipamount,
  partopsep=0pt,
  itemsep=0pt,
  align=left,
  resume,
}
\newenvironment{thm}{\thminner\item}{\endthminner}

\AtBeginDocument{\setlength{\parindent}{1.5em}}
\frenchspacing

\begin{document}

% this is just to get the first real theorem to be numbered 14
\begin{thm}\setcounter{thminneri}{14}\end{thm}
\newpage

It will next be shown that referential opacity afflicts also
the so-called \emph{modal} contexts `Necessarily~\dots' and
`Possibly~\dots', at least when those are given the sense of
\emph{strict} necessity and possibility as in Lewis's modal
logic.\footnote{Lewis [1],\dots}
According to the strict sense of `necessarily' and `possibly',
these statements would be regarded as true:
\begin{thm}\label{9gt7}
$9$ is necessarily greater than $7$,
\end{thm}
\begin{thm}
Necessarily if there is life on the Evening Star then there
is life on the Evening Star,
\end{thm}
\begin{thm}
The number of planets is possibly less than~$7$,
\end{thm}
and these as false:
\begin{thm}
The number of planets is necessarily greater than~$7$,
\end{thm}
\begin{thm}
Necessarily if there is life on the Evening Star then there
is life on the Morning Star,
\end{thm}
\begin{thm}
$9$ is possibly less than $7$.
\end{thm}
The general idea of strict modalities…

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I suggest using instead a custom `enumerate-like`  environment. It uses a very simple code with `enumitem`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{myprop}{enumerate}{1}%
\setlist[myprop]{label =(\arabic*), resume, wide=0pt, leftmargin=*}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{myprop}
\item Necessarily if there is life on the Evening Star then
there is life on the Evening Star. Necessarily if there is life on the Evening Star then
there is life on the Evening Star.
\item \label{prop:2}Necessarily if there is life on the Evening Star then
there is life on the Evening Star. Necessarily if there is life on the Evening Star then
there is life on the Evening Star.
\end{myprop}
\lipsum[11]
\begin{myprop}
\item \label{prop:3}Necessarily if there is life on the Evening Star then
there is life on the Evening Star. Necessarily if there is life on the Evening Star then
there is life on the Evening Star.
\end{myprop}

From propositions \ref{prop:2} and \ref{prop:3}, we see that …

\end{document}
```

*Edit (22-05)*:

[image]

If you don't want to type type  `item` each time, you caan replace the above code with

```
 \newenvironment{myprop}%
{\enumerate[label=(\arabic*), resume, wide=0pt, labelwidth=\dimexpr 2cm-\labelsep, leftmargin=2cm]\item }%
{\endenumerate}
```

Comment: thanks!  is there a way to increase the indentation (leaving the label at the margin)?

Comment: `wide=0pt` will always leave the label at the margin. For the indentation, you can set `leftmargin` to another value (`*` corresponds to the default label width+ \labelsep).

Comment: this doesn't affect the first line

Comment: labelsep=* does it

Comment: Together with `leftmargin=`? I was precisely trying ` labelsep=2cm`, say, and it seemed to work, but I couldn't test what happens when the counter has more digits.

Comment: yes, I used `wide=0pt, leftmargin=2em, labelsep=*`

Comment: When the counter has more digits, you have to compensate, which will require some trial and error. I suggest this instead, supposing you want a left margin at 2em: `wide=0pt, leftmargin=2em, labelwidth=\dimexpr 2em-\labelsep\relax`

Comment: since i would never use this for more than one item, would it be possible to dispense with the \item without wrapping this inside a second environment?

Comment: Please see my edit for this.