# How to add space before word?

Tags: spacing

I want to write text like this, where the word **circumference** should come under the word **When**.
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Could you please post a compilable code?

Comment: Isn't this identical to your previous question [How to write/align the text in the given format?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/535802/134144)?

Comment: This may be helpful: [After “Theorem”, “Definition” the actual content should start at the same indent](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/230557)